# Setting React state from JSON data in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I need to fetch `json` data and iterate over it, fetching some more `json` data later, and finally setting React states. I'd like to use a general function to handle all file requests. I'd also like to handle different types of errors (`404` and `json` parsing, mostly).

I've read [How to use async functions in useEffect](https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect)  and several other relevant articles, but whatever I try to do outside of my `fetchData` function, I keep getting only Promises instead of data.

Also, this only needs to be done once, when the main `App.js` load. Is it good practice to use an Effect for that, or should it be done at the top of the file, before the `App` component itself (which needs the data)?

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(url) {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        headers : { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
      })
      if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(`File not found: ${url}`)
      } else {
        const json = await response.json()
          .then(res => { return res })
          .catch(err => { return Promise.reject(`JSON Error (${url}): ${err}`) })
        // I can use "json" here...
      }
    }

    // ...but I need it here
    const json = fetchData('data/initial-data.json')
      .catch(err => console.log('Error ' + err))
    // to iterate over its contents with more calls to fetchData
    for (const item in json) {
      const moreData = fetchData(`data/moredata-${item}.json`)
        .catch(err => console.log(`Error: ${err}`))
      // do something with moreData
      // such as setState
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: TL;DR `fetch()` does not return a rejected promise when the response status is unsuccessful. You need to check `a.ok` first

Comment: Thank you. I'm deleting the question.

Comment: There's no need to delete it. You won't be penalised and it can act as a signpost for other users with similar problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: Is it OK if I rephrase the question with more details because it's a bit more involved than that, and although your response helped I'm banging my head against Promises for the last 24 hours in a rather simple scenario.

Comment: Looks like youare mixing async/await with `then()`, I think you should use one or ther other, not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return the json from the fetchData function and `await` it where you need it:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(url) {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        headers : { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      })

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to fetch ${url}, got ${response.status}`)
      }

      // note the return
      return await response.json()
    }

    // Note need the IIFE wrapper here because you
    // can't return a Promise from the useEffect callback
    (async function() {
      try {
        const initialData = await fetchData(whatever)
        const allData = await Promise.all(initialData.map(async (data) => {
           try {
             // fetch and return more data
             const moreData = await fetchData(data.whatever)
             return moreData
           } catch (err) {
             // do something with error, can return it or some
             // sentinel value like null
             return err
           }
        }))

        // setState, filtering out the failures
        setState(allData.filter(x => !(x instanceof Error))
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('failed initial fetch')
      }
    })()
  }, [])
```

On a side note don't mix `.then`/`.catch` with `async`/`await` in the same expression, and don't reject with strings as many Promise rejection handling code implicitly assumes the thing that caused the rejection is an actual error instance. If you wouldn't `throw` it don't reject a Promise with it.

Comment: Thank you. I copied the entire code block to try and understand it, but there seems to be a syntax error somewhere. I believe you are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the `try/catch` block inside `Promise.all`, which should end with `}))`. But more importantly, I get an "unexpected keyword `await` right after `const moreData`.

Comment: Also, I believe `got ${response.statusCode}` should return `response.status` or `response.statusText`, as `statusCode` is not defined.

Comment: Seems to work if you add `async` before the `(data)` function inside `map`.

Comment: Good catches, I dashed that off right after work and got distracted by life. Fixed.